# How to draw segment of circle at the bottom of view [android]?

Tags: android, android-drawable

My activity should look like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what's the best way to show the segment of the circle between top and bottom views.

I'd like to avoid saving the segment as image.

Is there a way to show it using `drawable` xml (I've tried to achieve this using `oval`, but I don't know how to make is so "flat")?

Maybe drawing on `canvas`?

Comment: try to create a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class passed to `ShapeDrawable` constructor (most likely you will draw it with the help of `Path#quadTo` method

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try

Comment: just for the clarity i m asking you need the output like image you gave on your question right ?

Comment: why not just have a background color and a big circle in a drawable? It does not matter if 80% of the circle is offscreen. Or you could use 2 rectangles (top & bottom ) and an arcshape same color for the bend

Comment: @jiteshmohite, right. I've removed unnecessary widgets for simplify, but the background of the activity should look like the image that I attached

Comment: @ChristianStengel,>why not just have a background color and a big circle in a drawable -- not sure how to move the circle outside the screen area correctly - to have the same angle of segment for different screen sizes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think option 3 is the best, you can control exactly what you're drawing but you don't loose OOP karma points

**OPTION 1**

You can create a custom `View` for your top `View` and implement the drawing yourself like this, I'm subclassing `RelativeLayout` here but you can subclass whatever `View` you want

```
public class CurveBgRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public CurveBgRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        path = new Path();

        float horizontalOffset = w * .8f;
        float top = -h * .8f;
        float bottom = h;

        RectF ovalRect = new RectF(-horizontalOffset, top, w + horizontalOffset, bottom);
        path.lineTo(ovalRect.left, top);
        path.arcTo(ovalRect, 0, 180, false);
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (path != null)
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and then in your xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.CurveBgRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OPTION 2**

You can create an xml drawable as a background for your top `View`, the only problem here is that the horizontal stretch of the circle is given with a size in dp, so it's not relative to the `View`'s size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="500dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:top="-40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />    
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="30dp"
        android:bottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OPTION 3**

```
public class CurveBottomDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Path path = new Path();

    public CurveBottomDrawable(int color) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0xffff0000);

        path.reset();
        Rect bounds = getBounds();

        float horizontalOffset = bounds.width() * .8f;
        float top = -bounds.height() * .8f;
        float bottom = bounds.height();

        RectF ovalRect = new RectF(-horizontalOffset, top, bounds.width() + horizontalOffset, bottom);
        path.lineTo(ovalRect.left, top);
        path.arcTo(ovalRect, 0, 180, false);
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
    }

}
```

and then set it programmatically

```
myView.setBackground(new CurveBottomDrawable(0xffff0000));
```

Comment: I feel like `onDraw()` won't be called because `setWillNotDraw(false)` hasn't been performed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first option is what I was looking for

Comment: @lelloman, I've checked the first solution. It will start work after `setWillNotDraw(false)`, otherwise `ViewGroup`'s `onDraw()` won't be called.

Comment: I see, so probably it was working for me because I set the background color so the ViewGroup has to draw..?

Comment: How to make curve more deep ?

Comment: @akshaybhange what option are you looking at?

Comment: Looking for 1st and 3rd ..  both the solution have same method

Comment: you need to tweak the coefficient (.8f in both cases) for horizontal offset and top

Comment: It is not making much difference. And if I set coefficient to .5f top left side becomes curve.

Comment: this could mean that canvas and bounds don't have the same width

Comment: Option two attribute height available in API level 23.